# General error: 1364 Field 'household_head_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `s_d_o_h_category_households`

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert the data into my s_d_o_h_category_households table that has one to one relationship with household_head table, sdoh_category_household table has one to many relationship with sdoh_category, and sdoh_category table has one to one relationship with sdoh table.

here is the schema for visualization:

[image]

When I tried to insert the data using this form and hit submit, it caused the error.

[image]

[image]

**create_household blade :**

```
 <form action="{{route('admin.household.store')}}" method="POST" >
                    @csrf



                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <label for="floatingSelect"> Name</label>
                      </div>

                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="purok" id="purok">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Purok</option>
                            @foreach ($puroks as $purok)
                            <option value="{{$purok->id}}">{{$purok->purok_num}}</option>
                            @endforeach

                           </select>

                        <label for="floatingSelect"> Purok</label>
                      </div>




                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="residence" id="residence">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Residence</option>
                            @foreach($residenceCategories as $residenceCategory)
                                <option value="{{ $residenceCategory->id }}">{{ $residenceCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect"> Residence</label>
                      </div>



                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="construction" id="construction">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select House Construction</option>

                            @foreach($constructionCategories as $constructionCategory)
                                <option value="{{ $constructionCategory->id }}">{{ $constructionCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach


                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect"> House Construction</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="water_source" id="water_source">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Water Source</option>

                            @foreach($waterSourceCategories as $waterSourceCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $waterSourceCategory->id }}">{{ $waterSourceCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Water Source</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="toilet" id="toilet">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Toilet Facility</option>

                            @foreach($toiletCategories as $toiletCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $toiletCategory->id }}">{{ $toiletCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Toilet Facility</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="electricity" id="electricity">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Electricity Source</option>
                            @foreach($electricityCategories as $electricityCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $electricityCategory->id }}">{{ $electricityCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Electricity Source</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="income" id="income">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Combined Family Income</option>
                            @foreach($incomeCategories as $incomeCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $incomeCategory->id }}">{{ $incomeCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Combined Family Income</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="religion" id="religion">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Religion</option>
                            @foreach($religionCategories as $religionCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $religionCategory->id }}">{{ $religionCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Religion</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Family Type</option>
                            @foreach($familyCategories as $familyCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $familyCategory->id }}">{{ $familyCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Family Type</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="disposal" id="disposal">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Garbage Disposal</option>

                            @foreach($garbageCategories as $garbageCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $garbageCategory->id }}">{{ $garbageCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach


                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Garbage Disposal</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="dental" id="dental">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Dental Healthcare</option>
                            @foreach($dentalCategories as $dentalCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $dentalCategory->id }}">{{ $dentalCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Dental Health Care</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="preventive" id="preventive">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Preventive Measures</option>
                            @foreach($preventiveCategories as $preventiveCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $preventiveCategory->id }}">{{ $preventiveCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Preventive Procedure</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="medical" id="medical">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Medical Services</option>
                             @foreach($medicalCategories as $medicalCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $medicalCategory->id }}">{{ $medicalCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Medical Services</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="healthcare" id="healthcare">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select healthcare</option>

                            @foreach($healthcaretCategories as $healthcaretCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $healthcaretCategory->id }}">{{ $healthcaretCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Healthcare</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="behaviour" id="behaviour">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Exposure to Unhealthy Behaviour</option>

                            @foreach($exposureCategories as $exposureCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $exposureCategory->id }}">{{ $exposureCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Exposure to Unhealthy Behaviour</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="insurance" id="insurance">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Health Insurance</option>

                            @foreach($insuranceCategories as $insuranceCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $insuranceCategory->id }}">{{ $insuranceCategory->category }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Health Insurance</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="hazards" id="hazards">
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Environmental Hazard</option>

                            @foreach ($env_hazards  as $env_hazard)
                             <option value="{{$env_hazard->id}}">{{$env_hazard->env_hazard}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect">Environmental Hazards</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="adults" placeholder="Number of Adults" required>
                        <label for="floatingSelect"> Number of Adults</label>
                      </div>





                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-pill" type="submit" value="submit">Add Household</button>

                </form>
```

**SDOH table:**

[image]

**SDOHCategory table:**

[image]

**SDOHCategoryHousehold table:**

[image]

**HouseholdHead table:**

[image]

I am new to eloquent and query builder that is why I am so confused dealing with complex model relationship.

**controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $env_hazards = EnvHazard::all();
    $categories = SDOHCategory::all();


    $residenceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Residence')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $constructionCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'House Construction')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $waterSourceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Water Source')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $toiletCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Toilet Facility')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $electricityCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Electricity Source ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $incomeCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Combined Family Income')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $religionCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Religion ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $familyCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Family Type')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $incomeCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Combined Family Income ')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $garbageCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Garbage Disposal')->first()->sdoh_category;


    $dentalCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Dental Healthcare ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $preventiveCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Preventive Procedure')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $medicalCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Medical Services ')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $healthcaretCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Healthcare  ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $exposureCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Exposure to Unhealthy Behavior')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $insuranceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Health Insurance ')->first()->sdoh_category;


    return view('household_create', compact('puroks', 'categories', 'env_hazards', 'residenceCategories', 'constructionCategories' ,'waterSourceCategories','toiletCategories', 'electricityCategories', 'incomeCategories', 'religionCategories', 'familyCategories'  ,'dentalCategories', 'preventiveCategories', 'medicalCategories', 'healthcaretCategories', 'exposureCategories', 'insuranceCategories', 'garbageCategories'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $household = new HouseholdHead;

    //other fields
    $household->name = $request->name;
    $household->purok_id = $request->purok;
    $household->env_hazard_id = $request->hazards;
    $household->number_of_adults = $request->adults;

    $sdohCategory = new SDOHCategoryHousehold;
    $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->residence;
    $sdohCategory->save();
    



    return redirect()->route('admin.household.index')->with('success', 'Household Added Successfully!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As error message says HouseholdHead id is missing and it's required to create that row.

Edit your store method in this way:

```
    $household = HouseholdHead::create([
         'name' => $request->get('name'),
         'purok_id ' => $request->get('purok'),
         'env_hazard_id ' => $request->get('hazards'),
         'number_of_adults ' => $request->get('adults'),
    ]);

    //Now $household contains freshly created HouseholdHead resource 
    //with db assigned id and you can use this id to create
    //SHODCategoryHousehold

    $sdohCategory = SDOHCategoryHousehold::create([
         'household_head_id' => $household->id,
         'sdoh_category_id' => $request->get('residence')
    ]);
```

Just check that HouseholdHead model has properties that you use inside create method in $fillable property:

```
    model \App\Models\HouseholdHead;

    class HouseholdHead{
         protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'purok_id',
              'env_hazard_id',
              'number_of_adults'
         ]
    }
```

And the same for SDOHCategoryHousehold.

Read this for more
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: when I tried to save other fields aside from residence :  

       $sdohCategory->household_head_id = $household->id;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->residence;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->construction;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->water_source;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->toilet;   etc.....

it only save the last data  like the toilet. How to save all the fields?

Comment: Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment. As I said in the answer, properties that you want to use into create, must be present into model's fillable property.